# Correct syntax with nested smarty inside javascript

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, smarty

I am retrieving a smarty array 'data' and I want to store it inside a javascript variable 'store' :

```
{if isset({$data})}
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var store = {ldelim}{rdelim};
            {foreach from=$data key=k item=v}
                var index = {$k};
                store.index = {$v};
            {/foreach}
                alert(store);
        </script>
    {/if}
```

but I have no alert output. Someone could help ?

Rmk : I need that to run this

```
$("input").each(function(index) {
                    return this.value = store.index;
                });
```

Edit : Inthe source code, I get  var store = {};

Comment: How does the generated code look like?

Comment: I am told store is not a defined variable ??

Comment: If you "View Source" on the page, how does the generated javascript look like? Please edit your question with this information.

Comment: @hank Indeed, I only have this <script type="text/javascript">
                var store = {};
                
            </script>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of going the long and very hard to read way of trying to create a javascript object/array via Smarty, try this;

```
$arr = json_encode(array(array('key1' => 'value1'), array('key2' => 'value2')));
$smarty->assign('data', $arr);
```

and in the template;

```
<script>
var store = {$data};
</script>
```

So, we are letting PHP create a valid javascript object for us and assign that string to smarty, which simply created a variable and assigns that string.

Answer (score -2):

You have written a wrong tag. In Smarty, to enable JavaScript you must use `{literal}` tag.

For exmaple:

```
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
// All your regular javascript code.....
</script>
{/literal}
```

Comment: You don't have to, you can use `{ldelim}` and `{rdelim}` to write out curly braces.

Comment: That's not what `{literal}` does, you've misunderstood the purpose of it. It's not *required* to use JavaScript, and it definitely doesn't *enable* JavaScript.

Comment: as far as i knw {literal} is required in smarty

Comment: Please see the manual for literal on Smarty website. "{literal} tags allow a block of data to be taken literally. This is typically used around Javascript or stylesheet blocks where {curly braces} would interfere with the template delimiter syntax."